# how to define SampleGattAttributes in the following code?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

```
public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
                UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
```

SampleGattAttributes, appears in red colour,means unresolved symbol. How to define this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

Add SampleGattAttributes class in your package given below and import class.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

    public class SampleGattAttributes {
        private static HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap();
        public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
       static {
            // Sample Services.
            attributes.put("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Heart Rate Service");
            // Sample Characteristics.
            attributes.put(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT, "Heart Rate Measurement");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an example from the [Official Google Archive](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-BluetoothLeGatt/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/SampleGattAttributes.java) or [Official Android](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/blob/master/BluetoothLeGatt/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/SampleGattAttributes.java) repository for the `SampleGattAttributes`

Here is the full example:

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * This class includes a small subset of standard GATT attributes for demonstration purposes.
 */
public class SampleGattAttributes {
    private static HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap();
    public static String HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT = "00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    public static String CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

    static {
        // Sample Services.
        attributes.put("0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Heart Rate Service");
        attributes.put("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Device Information Service");
        // Sample Characteristics.
        attributes.put(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT, "Heart Rate Measurement");
        attributes.put("00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "Manufacturer Name String");
    }

    public static String lookup(String uuid, String defaultName) {
        String name = attributes.get(uuid);
        return name == null ? defaultName : name;
    }
}
```